# Is it less efficient to write dynamic CSS stylesheets with a PHP file extension?

Tags: php, html, css

Ive been trying to think of ways to dynamically change a style based off of input from a website back-end (through a language like PHP).  Normally I have my stylesheets be separate CSS-extension files, but these won't allow for PHP tags natively.  It is, after all, extra markup in your HTML file than having all of your styles be in a separate file.  Is the usage of the HTML `<style>` tag perhaps slower/less efficient than using a stylesheet?

Comment: Gah, I voted to close as "not a real question," but anyways, this question is more suited for [Programmers.SE]. And I see nothing wrong with it, it minimizes the use of PHP for preference-based systems.

Comment: @Purmou I see no reason to move this to Programmers, it's a *technical* question.

Comment: @deceze: Because the phrasing of the question implies that an answer would be based on opinion or style/technique. Which it would be regardless of what the spec says. The spec can say one thing, but it doesn't have to be the best practice if the spec says it.

Comment: @Purmou Opinion doesn't really work on Programmers, we prefer specific conceptual (whiteboardy) questions, with little room for debate and/or opinion, and even more specific, references backed answers. As for this question, and almost all "best practice" questions, there's one thing missing: best practice for what? cereallarceny answers will differ based on what exactly you are building and your exact requirements. There's rarely a silver bullet...

Comment: I asked the question not to invoke a discussion, but to request a specific example of which might be faster.  I do not think this is really an opinion-based question at all in, but perhaps I should reword the question itself to avoid using phrases like "best practice".

Comment: This line confuses me a bit: "It is, after all, dirtier markup than having all of your styles be in a separate file" - could you clarify that (more for my own understanding than anything else). Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely, I revised my question.  By dirtier markup I meant that it would be preferable to have HTML in your PHP file and keep CSS in a CSS file to avoid having more languages in a single place of code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The W3C Recommendation for CSS 2.1 contains a section on [Conformance: Requirements and Recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/conform.html#text-css), which makes no reference to filename extension but does state:

> ### 3.4 The text/css content type
>
> CSS style sheets that exist in separate files are sent over the Internet as a sequence of bytes accompanied by encoding information. The structure of the transmission, termed a **message entity**, is defined by RFC 2045 and RFC 2616 (see [[RFC2045]](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/refs.html#ref-RFC2045) and [[RFC2616]](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/refs.html#ref-RFC2616)). A message entity with a content type of "text/css" represents an independent CSS document. The "text/css" content type has been registered by RFC 2318 ([[RFC2318]](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/refs.html#ref-2318)).

Therefore, provided that the file is served with the `text/css` content type (and that any cacheing concerns are addressed as mentioned in [@Fluffeh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11814843/623041)), you should not have a problem.  In PHP, the content type can be set with a call to [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) before any output is sent:

```
<? header('Content-type: text/css'); ?>
```

Comment: Missing this out meant my style was broken in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE... this solved it, so thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am not so sure that you want to do too much inside the CSS. If anything, I would suggest maybe adding some extra classes rather than doing too much dynamically. If anything, you might be better off with using PHP to pick a CSS sheet to include, but leave them as CSS. If you keep using the same file, the user can cache it, it appears much quicker. It would be better to have a stylesheet of 50k that is used ocne then cached rather than a stylesheet of 10k that is downloaded with each and every single page.

Comment: One can set the `Expires:`, `Last-Modified:`, `Cache-Control:` and `Pragma:` HTTP headers to control the way that caches (both browser and proxy) store the output, as desired.