# Chrome and IE not recognising dynamic PHP CSS stylesheet

Tags: php, css

In the head of my html page I have:

```
<link media="screen" href="tabs.css.php?tabs=374,375,376,377,378,379,381,380" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The CSS is dynamically created based on the tabs parameter.

This works in IE9, but not in Chrome or Firefox. However, when I tried saving the generated CSS as "tabs.css" and pointing Chrome to that, it worked. That doesn't help me much though because I need the style to be dynamically generated.

How can I get Firefox and Chrome to recognise the stylesheet?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by adding this line to the top (before any output is sent, even a blank line) of my PHP file which generates the stylesheet:

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

It seems that when the file has a .css extension it is correctly recognised by Firefox and Chrome as CSS, but not when it's got a .php extension. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11815010/612253) has some links that might be useful to you if you want to learn more.

Comment: Well Setting correct content type is always be must when you output non-html content from a php file.